# Authorize a user account with a public key ssh

Tags: ssh

I got a server and I want all my users to access using their private key.

- Users generate with `ssh-keygen -t rsa` a couple of public and private key. I'm given the public key, with format:

`ssh-rsa  AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDe++u83PipzF1YmdJ0/OI2ivt/lR7IED5gQ+IBuN97vayfazKKV8+NAGI3o+Qh1f7kCQk3J9km/9tIAPpWZQWZg95aPwkmx4QuYoI7kn/LLaOYtTgaAqU0z9TzP8k83Sth5D3ET4LnkNrfKUhiPQsN1+WnhRafEv3Hu3+mHU7d8KGVyI7yhRoGWFrmPGwobza0bDsjDrSo70TCcMja8UgUTabukUmF3oj92tVKQZ+doNn4x1084rPKfky+5WGXbcuXTZnmWZRDOMqHsXicXp2m0x26oYJ0lTUnAKzWt25t2weKn24ynZzBEFRJi8ndWG+BKFiQsbSlS8ntWtJ7+9vf test@test-PC`

Now in the server, I've created an account called `test` and I would like to **Authorize** such public key with user `test`.

I have already set within `sshd_config` lines:

```
Protocol 2
Match User root
    PasswordAuthentication no
Match Group foreigners
    PasswordAuthentication no
Match all

AuthorizedKeysFile      .ssh/authorized_keys``
```

Should I now insert within `authorized_keys` file the public key? If so, how can I bind such key with its desired user (test)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to copy/append the public key of everyone who should access the account `test` to the `authorized_keys` file for this user, which usually is located in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` (where `~/` expands to the home directory, again usually `/home/test/`).

That's all there is to be done.

Comment: I am using in /home/test, ``mkdir .ssh`` to create such dir, but it says that the file already exists. I am executing after that ``ls -l`` and nothing appears... Is that normal? What sould I do? Thank you.

Comment: @TDRS file/directory names that start with a period (`.`) are considered hidden files.  To see them with `ls` you need to use `ls -a` or `ls -A`

Comment: Yes, this is normal. The directory is named `.ssh`. By default, files and directories with a leading dot in their file name are not displayed by `ls`. Use `ls -la`.

Comment: Oh I have just noticed that by creating ``touch .ssh/authorized_keys``. Thank you.

Comment: I'm using Alpine Linux, and neither ``/var/log/secure`` nor ``/var/log/auth.log`` exists... How can I see people who access via ssh in alpine linux? Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

Here is what I would do :

- Once your users have already created their public / privates key thay have to run the command bellow in order to export their public key to the server.

  ```
  ssh-copy-id username@ip_address
  ```
- On the server you have to modify your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file and add the following

  ```
  Match User username
          AuthenticationMethods publicKey
  ```
- If it is for all users just put the `AuthenticationMethods publicKey` statement
- Then restart sshd service and it should work

Cheers